# Decoding message that was previously encoded

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to figure out how to reverse a message that was encoded by splitting a string into two arrays then joining them.

The encoding code looks like this:

```
def encode_railroad(secret_phrase):
    toggle      = True
    upper_track = []
    lower_track = []

    for word in secret_phrase.split(" "):
        if toggle:
            upper_track.append(word)
            toggle = False
            continue
        lower_track.append(word)
        toggle = True

    return "{}\r\n{}".format(" ".join(upper_track), " ".join(lower_track))
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would reverse this. For example, if 'hi my name is ryan' becomes 'hi name ryan my is' how would I reverse it back to 'hi my name is ryan'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split the string, then split the list into two sublists. Then use the sublists to generate target string.

```
def decode(msg):
    lst = msg.split()
    idx = (len(lst) // 2) + 1 if len(lst) % 2 else len(lst) // 2
    a, b = lst[0: idx], lst[idx:]
    for i in range(len(a) - len(b)):
        b.append('')
    return ' '.join([' '.join(x) for x in zip(a, b)])

print(decode('hi name ryan my is'))
```

**Output:**

```
hi my name is ryan
```